# Python how to control keyboard input

Tags: python, keyboard

I was developing a calculator UI in python and wanted the period to only be inputted once. I was able to disable the button after it was used once, but what if they use the keyboard. How do I block the "." Key in the keyboard after being used once?

Answer (score 0):

You have an event listener somewhere in your code which handles the keypresses. Check in that function whether the key is the "." or not. And if it is the "." button, check if it has been pressed already before showing it on the display.